# Add text to LESS parameter

Tags: css, less

Is it possible to add text to the parameter supplied in Less?

```
@parameter:20

margin: @parameter + 'px';
```

The output would be

```
margin: 20px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [variable interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation):

```
@parameter: 20;    
margin: ~"@{parameter}px";
```

Or in your case, [`unit` built-in function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-unit) can also be used:

```
@parameter: 20;
margin: unit(@parameter, px);
```

Both will result in `margin: 20px;`. ([Working example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40parameter%3A%2020%3B%20%20%20%20%5Cn%5Cn.using-builtin-function%20%7B%20%20%5Cn%20%20margin%3A%20~%5C%22%40%7Bparameter%7Dpx%5C%22%3B%20%20%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.using-variable-interpolation%20%7B%5Cn%20%20margin%3A%20unit(%40parameter%2C%20px)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D))

Answer (score 1):

```
margin: @parameter * 1px;
```

Works perfectly for me, I´m sure this was also somewhere on stack overflow before.

Edit, found it: [Negate a numerical variable and add 'px' to it in LessCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384803/negate-a-numerical-variable-and-add-px-to-it-in-lesscss)